# Is it possible to save a shortcut to a specific control panel page?

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

Every so often I need to reset/check a network adapter. It happens just rarely enough that every time, I forget how I did it and must stumble through control panel and settings until I blunder onto:
[image]

Is there any way I can create a shortcut to `Control Panel\Network and Ethernet\Network Connections` on Windows 10?

Comment: Once you've found that page, you can also drag the adapters to the Desktop or other folder & create a shortcut to the adapter's Properties page.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on desktop > New > Shortcut
2. Write **ncpa.cpl**
3. Name your shortcut as you want
4. You can also change the icon by right click, choose property and click on the Change Icon button

Comment: Did you see @IGRACH's note - you might want to note this in your answer if he is correct

Comment: @Mr.Boy I have tested in my lab. Both of C:\Windows\System32\ncpa.cpl or ncpa.cpl is OK. Ludovic Omarini's answer is right. We don't need to put whole path in address part, ncpa.cpl is OK.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, right click on desktop to bring up options menu, select new and then select shortcut, then write ncpa.cpl. Though this can be easily expanded to create links to other Control Panel pages as well. Just replacet ncpa.cpl with the .cpl you want to create a shortcut for when creating shortcuts for other .cpl's.

Control Panel pages are saved as .cpl files in %windir%\system32 folder(C:\Windows\System32), I assume you are able to  use cmd, right? So I suggest you to run dir %windir%\system32*.cpl in cmd to list all .cpl files, then cd to %windir%\system32 and type their names and press enter one by one to see which control panel page each .cpl opens, then you can decide which control panel shortcuts you want to create.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit (2/15/2024) : Updated, improved answer per recent comments.

---

If you're interested in a specific adapter, by far the easiet solution is to right-click on the adapter and select `Create Shortcut`:
[image]

Because **Network Connections** is not an actual file system location, you'll eceive the familiar:

[image]

Click <kbd>Yes</kbd> and you have a shortcut on your Desktop that displays the adapter's **Properties** dialog with no intermediale windows open:

[image]

But if you want to create a shortcut to the **Network Connections** folder (or any folder that displays in an **Explorer** window) you can obtain the namespace path with this **PowerShell** snippet that you can copy and paste into a **PowerShell** console window. It displays the location and namespace path for all open **Explorer**/**Control Panel** windows:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()) |
   select LocationName,
          @{N = 'NameSpace Path';E={$_.Document.Folder.Self.Path}} |
Format-List
```

Output:

```
LocationName   : Network Connections
NameSpace Path : ::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}

LocationName   : Network and Sharing Center
NameSpace Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{8E908FC9-BECC-40F6-915B-F4CA0E70D03D}

LocationName   : Screenshots
NameSpace Path : C:\Users\keith\Screenshots
```

By prepending the `shell:` prefix, you obtain a path that can be pasted in the **Explorer** Address bar or a **Run** dialog:

- `shell:::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}`

To create a shortcut, specify the target as:
`explorer shell:::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}`

These virtual folders are somewhat "free-floating" and can actually be specified without any "navigation", i.e.:

- `shell:::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}`

When launched using this format, the <kbd>­↑</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> buttons return directly to the virtual Desktop.

If you prefer a more "built-in" look, these CLSIDs can be added as subkeys under:

- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`

[image]

Which place the custom icon on the Desktop with no shortcut arrow and, somewhat ironically, give you the right-click option `Create Shortcut`! :
[image]

And actually, the shortcut produced in that manner is an IDList-only (can't edit target) shortcut that, since it's not launching its own **Explorer** process, won't open a sparate window if launched from within a folder, but rather navigate its containing folder to its target:

[image]

### End of updated answer

---

Oringinal Anser  below...
I noticed this answer used a different CLSID for the Network Connections folder that I must have found just by searching HKCE\CLSID. Both are functional; both are defined identicallly under HKCR\CLSID. No clue as to why...

---

You can also access the folder via the [Shell Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro) using its CLSID, **`{992CFFA0-F557-101A-88EC-00DD010CCC48}`**.

```
shell:::{992CFFA0-F557-101A-88EC-00DD010CCC48}
   - or -
shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\3\::{992CFFA0-F557-101A-88EC-00DD010CCC48}
```

will open the folder when pasted into a **Run...** dialog or the **Explorer** Address Bar.

So to create shortcuts, use the following targets:

```
explorer shell:::{992CFFA0-F557-101A-88EC-00DD010CCC48}
   - or -
explorer shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\3\::{992CFFA0-F557-101A-88EC-00DD010CCC48}
```

Comment: -1 for not saying anything about how to *find* the CLSID for that control panel page (or ideally more generally any control panel page you want). Would've been an instant +1 from me if it did.

Comment: I was able to find [this page with a list of CLSIDs](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/list-of-windows-11-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts.1075/), which combined with this answer was enough to let me create a shortcut to the page I wanted. I found it by typing "windows how to find CLSID of a control panel page" into DuckDuckGo. An *official* upstream page by Microsoft would be more ideal. But maybe there's no better way for the typical person than just googling, and if so, then just saying *that* in the answer would flip this to a +1 for me.

Comment: In every other way **this is the best answer**, because it's more flexible. For example, every page of accessibility settings has a CLSID, but there's no `.cpl` file for accessibility at all (at least not in the System32 folder, and none of the other answers suggest anywhere else to look).

Comment: @mtraceur: -1 for waiting three years to comment. ;-).   I shall edit to improve the answer  with not only an answer to your question, but a delightfully simple approach to the OPs particular situation.  Not sure if that will be tonight or tomorrow, though...

Comment: Haha, you're right. I sat on this for years, biding my time, but I realize what I did was wrong now, and I am deeply sorry. I totally understand if you never forgive me though. (Do let me know when you edit the post, I'd love to flip the vote.)

Comment: @mtraceur: Check out what I must say, wtih all modesty, is a vastly improved answer.!

Comment: Excellent! I agree, this is much improved. My issues are addressed and then some. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Ludovic Omarini sad but when adding shortcut you need to put whole path in address part:

`C:\Windows\System32\ncpa.cpl`.

And you can put that shortcut anywhere you want.

Comment: It would be better to edit your answer to answer fully, not reference another answer... or equally Ludovic might expand his answer.